# Unwanted Blurring Texture at a Distance

Tags: texturing, camera

I applied a texture to my road mesh, and for some reason it blurs the white lines in the texture after a certain distance from the viewport camera. Here's a snapshot of it, with camera settings visible. I haven't encountered this with textures before, but I'm still new to using them, so I don't know if it's a camera issue or a texture issue. I painted the road lines onto the texture file in an external program and used the saved image file as the texture.

[image]

Comment: You may need to post your blend file. Don't forget to pack the image texture before you do.

Comment: Related : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6683/how-to-get-anisotropic-filtering-in-blender-internal

Comment: What do you need to see in the file that you can't see here?

Comment: @AnthonyForwood posting your blend file may allow to check the possible reasons of your problem. Here only the result can be seen, not the causes.

Comment: I didn't ask why you want to se the file. I'm asking what problems you think might be there to see that you can't see in the image.

Comment: If I remember correctly this is [Mipmapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap)