# What is this blur/antialiasing effect in the game engine?

Tags: texturing, game-engine, camera, blur, antialiasing

What is this (unwanted) blur/antialiasing effect that I have in the game engine?
The effect worsen with the distance from the camera. Also, it seems to increase in a discrete (not continuous) manner. It also affects my bumping maps. I tried to change the AA setting but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: It has to do with anisotropic filtering. See here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62941/16835

Comment: I have read a bunch of theory about texture filtering (Nearest-neighbor, Bilinear, Trilinear, Anisotropic, etc), Mip maps, Rip Maps and so on. I feel like I do grasp these topics now. However I still have doubts about Anisotropic filtering, namely the way the trapezoidal footprint is calculated and applied.

Comment: This article by [Nvidia] (http://www.geforce.com/whats-new/guides/aa-af-guide#1) is what confuses me even more. It seems to relate the concept of Anisotropic filtering to MIP map 'scaling' (thus, RIP maps?). Other resources treat these as related, but still independent topics. In the end I was able to improve the visual quality of my model but I feel like I do not understand what is going on underneath the BGE surface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to mipmap settings, you can change in user preferences > systems > mipmap

[image]

**But this only work inside blender**.

In game (standalone) you need a script.

```
from bge import render

render.setMipmapping(0)
```

related: [Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.render.html?highlight=mipmap#bge.render.getMipmapping)

Comment: Thank you, `render.setMipmapping()` did actually change something. So did `render.setAnisotropicFiltering()`. To my understanding the, **Mipmaps** and **Anisotropic Filtering** settings under "Blender User Preferences" are ignored in the Game Engine. However I'm not sure about **GPU Mipmap Generation** and **16 Bit Float Textures**. Also, the documentation says the return values for `render.getMipmapping()`should be `RAS_MIPMAP_NONE, RAS_MIPMAP_NEAREST, RAS_MIPMAP_LINEAR` but there are actually exposed as numbers: 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: There are several other things I do not understand. Do `RAS_MIPMAP_NONE, RAS_MIPMAP_NEAREST, RAS_MIPMAP_LINEAR` refer to the way the mipmaps are generated (Nearest-neighbor interpolation, Linear mipmap filtering etc, as described in [wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering). Does this mean that BGE does not support **Bilinear Filtering**? How many MIP maps are generated when I turn this on? and when?

Comment: RAS_MIPMAP_NONE = 0, RAS_MIPMAP_NEAREST = 1, etc. And yes they refer the way the mipmaps are generated, but im not  sure about bilinear. and don't really know how many mipmap are generated.

Comment: GPU Mipmap tells if you want generate the mipmap with GPU (active) or CPU (deactive), about 16 bit float textures i really don't have any idea.

Comment: It is very unclear whether `RAS_MIPMAP_LINEAR` indicates MIP maps generated by means of (bi)linear filtering OR a linear interpolation between the results obtained by sampling two consecutive MIP maps generated by means of Nearest-neighbor interpolation. I think the number of generated MIP maps is 8. What seems to be not supported in the game engine is RIP maps as I don't find any reference to it. I still have doubts on the implementation of anisotropic filter but I will report this in the main question.

Comment: Maybe you should make another question. Also I couldn't found any references in blender documentation

Comment: i found this short references [http://bgepython.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Render/setMipmapping](http://bgepython.tutorialsforblender3d.com/Render/setMipmapping)

Comment: If Tutorialsforblender3D tells the truth, then the API nomenclature is very misleading as `RAS_MIPMAP_LINEAR` indicates what is commonly referred ad Trilinear filtering.

Comment: In this case the MIP maps themselves are probably generated by means of Bilinear filtering, then interpolation between the results obtained from the two nearest mipmap levels occurs, which is also referred as Trilinear filtering.

Comment: Maybe that the case, but my knowledge on the subject (filtering) is very very low or none at all. so I suggest that you make another question on the subject.

Comment: This [question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/help-me-grasp-anisotropic-filtering-af) provides some insight about Anisotropic Filtering