# Blurry textures in BGE

Tags: texturing, uv, game-engine

Lately I have invested in the BGE of blender. I decided to make a simple game, and it is very simple indeed. You are a cube that can hop and move around and climb up mountains. I have the textures all nice and crisp in blender, but when I save as a .app, the textures are blurry and disgusting. I have already searched YouTube and Google but have not found any results. Please help me!

In blender
[image]

Out of blender (published as .app)
[image]

Comment: This looks like bilinear texture filtering. Maybe try out the python script given in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78713/55213)

Comment: Darn! It still came out cruddy. Perhaps it is just my graphics card?